# Compatibility section for iphone app in Appstore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, app-store

We have an iPhone only app. It is default compatible with iPod and iPad. We dont want users to stop using our App in iPad and iPod. But, we wanted to be clear showing that in compatibility section in Appstore. I did a few search and found, we can add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities keys in the info.plist and restrict the compatibility. If we do that, will the app be listed in iPad and iPod appstores? Can the users download and use it?

How exactly can we change the compatibility section in Appstore? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: If the app isn't a universal app then it will not appear in an iPad user's app store search unless they specifically elect to see iPhone apps

Comment: yeah that is fine. But in iPhone applestore, under information, compatibility section it shows as 'Compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod touch. Can I change that just to compatible with iPhone ?

Comment: No, because it is compatible with iPad.  A Universal app will have the little '+' sign on the 'get' button as well as the text "This app is designed for both iPhone and iPad" and appear under "iPad Apps" in a search while an iPhone app will appear under "iPhone Apps"

Comment: Cool thanks a ton. I am not able to understand UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities properly. Is that only for restricting devices with certain features like camera, bluetooth, phone etc., If we use those keys, will it affect when we run the app in iPad or iPod?

Comment: Yes, say you had an app that was completely non-functional without a camera, you can use UIDeviceCapabilities to require a camera

Comment: Say, without phone option my app is completely non-functional, so I set UIDeviceCapabilities to require a phone in which case it limits to iPhone only. Will that stop showing my app in appstore when I try it from iPad or iPod? Can I download it in iPad or iPod.. Sorry, I am being a amateur here.. Bare with me..

Comment: it would probably prevent iPod and iPads from being able to download the app, but I am not sure as these devices can now make calls using handoff to a paired phone

Comment: @Paulw11 pls write ur comments as an answer